# Why isn't canonical livepatch working? ("nothing-to-apply")

Tags: upgrade, kernel, canonical-livepatch

We're running an Ubuntu 18.04.2 Bionic Beaver host and the new kernel upgrade with several security fixes just arrived. But livepatching shows that the old kernel is secure and doesn't attempt to live patch the kernel. I have downloaded and upgraded kernel upgrade (see the output below), but not rebooted the system yet. Do other people get the live patch, or is there something wrong with Canonical?

Thanks.

```
root@efk:~# uname -r
4.15.0-45-generic
root@efk:~# dpkg -l | grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic         4.15.0-45.48                                 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-4.15.0-46-generic         4.15.0-46.49                                 amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic                   4.15.0.46.48                                 amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
root@efk:~# canonical-livepatch status
client-version: 8.2.0
architecture: x86_64
cpu-model: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E7-4850 v3 @ 2.20GHz
last-check: 2019-03-07T11:51:30+01:00
boot-time: 2019-02-28T11:12:44+01:00
uptime: 168h39m18s
status:
- kernel: 4.15.0-45.48-generic
  running: true
  livepatch:
    checkState: checked
    patchState: nothing-to-apply
    version: ""
    fixes: ""

root@efk:~# canonical-livepatch refresh
Before refresh:

kernel: 4.15.0-45.48-generic
fully-patched: true
version: ""

After refresh:

kernel: 4.15.0-45.48-generic
fully-patched: true
version: ""

root@efk:~#
```

Why is canonical-livepatch status saying "patchState: nothing-to-apply"?

Comment: This probably means that the current kernel doesn't have security fixes.

Comment: Apparently, judging from the information on Ubuntu Security Notices, it appears to have security fixes. ==========================================================================
Ubuntu Security Notice USN-3901-1
March 05, 2019

linux, linux-aws, linux-gcp, linux-kvm, linux-oem, linux-oracle, linux-raspi2 vulnerabilities
==========================================================================

A security issue affects these releases of Ubuntu and its derivatives:

- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Summary:

Several security issues were fixed in the Linux kernel.

Comment: File a but at launchpad and then we'll see. This is not the best place to ask.

Comment: File a bug at launchpad? How to do that? I am new to this.

Comment: I have filed a bug at the Launchpad. Thanks for the tip. Hope my problem gets solved.

Comment: Please post an answer here if you get any interesting feedback.

Comment: Good, I hope to get some. Here's the bug filed: https://bugs.launchpad.net/canonical-livepatch-client/+bug/1818995

Comment: You could visit the bug report and say that bug affects you too if it does, so it gets maintainer's attention sooner.

Comment: I can't seem to find a reply to my bug report to Launchpad. It seems like it is discarded. Perhaps it is a kernel security fix that cannot be live patched but requires reboot.